# Renaming Android Text-To-Speech Voices

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, text-to-speech

Wondering if anyone has ever needed to try and print a list of “prettified” Voice names using Android TTS Library? The “offical” voice names look like this (with even more inconsistencies than this example shows):

- es-us-x-sfb-local
- fr-fr-x-vlf#male_1-local
- ja-jp-x-htm-network
- cy
- hr
- bs
- th-th-x-mol#female_2-local
- uk-UA-language
- th-th-x-mol#male_1-local
- en-gb-x-fis#female_1-local
- en-gb-x-srv#female_1-local
- sv-se-x-lfs-local
- fr-fr-x-vlf-network
- en-us-x-sfg#female_1-local
- en-US-language
- en-gb-x-rjs-local

Trying to get and end result something like: “English (UK) - Male 1" or (English (UK) - Female 2" but every time I think I’ve found a way to break the names down into consistent parsable pieces, another ‘name’ throws me off!

Comment: Even if you accomplished this, what are you going to do when the user has a different speech engine installed than you expect, and the voices (and names) are all completely different?

Comment: A very fair point, @NerdyBunz! Shame there's not really a nice naming system in place already. Oh well!

Comment: @NerdyBunz General speaking, other speech engine's naming systems tend to be much clearer.